# Caesar Cipher in javascript: cipher broken

Tags: javascript, string, for-in-loop, encryption

I'm building a Caesar Cipher in javascript. It uses a randomly set variable called `currentkey` as the cipher's key. it can be a number from -25 to +25, skipping 0.

I can't figure out why the function returns undefined in the beginning of the string, or why it translates the same letter for as long as the string goes, or even why that letter doesn't get translated at all.

```
var currentkey = 5  //for example
function convertKey(str) {
    var o_text = str;
    var o_letters = o_text.split("");
    var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','y','w','z']
    var c_text, _x = "";
    for (x in o_letters) {
        if (currentkey > 0) {
            _x = alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(x) + currentkey]
        } else {
            _x = alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(x) + (26 - currentkey)]
        }
        c_text = c_text + _x;
    }
    return c_text;
}
```

For example, running `convertKey("example")` returns `undefinedeeeeeee` (undefined + 7 times the first letter in "example").

Comment: You have 'w' in the wrong location in your array. It should be between 'v' and 'x', not after 'y'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `undefined` is a result of not initializing `c_text` before you try concatenate it with `_x`.

The code only works on one letter because `alphabet.indexOf(x)` returns `-1` (not found). When using `o_text = "abc"`, `x` equals 0, 1, and 2. Thus, the index of 0, 1, or 2 in `alphabet` is nonexistent (indicated by the `-1` result). You need to relate those numbers back to `o_text` by changing `indexOf(x)` to `indexOf(o_text[x])`. Also, to prevent going outside the bounds of your array, you need a modulus operation to wrap values greater than 26 (I've used `alphabet.length` to allow this code to work with other alphabets) back around into a valid region. Thus, the correct code would be as follows (note: I've moved 'w' in your array into its proper location alphabetically, as I assumed its location in your example was an error and not intentional):

```
var currentkey = 5  //for example
function convertKey(str) {
    var o_text = str;
    var o_letters = o_text.split("");
    var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    var c_text="", _x = "";
    for (x in o_letters) {
        if (currentkey > 0) {
            _x = alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(o_letters[x]) + currentkey) % alphabet.length]
        } else {
            _x = alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(o_letters[x]) + (26 - currentkey)) % alphabet.length]
        }
        c_text = c_text + _x;
    }
    return c_text;
}

alert(convertKey('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'));
```

This alert's `fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde`

Answer (score 3):

Implementation the Caesar Cipher algorithm in JavaScript is very interesting due to the fact that JavaScripts lacks true modulo operator. The % is just the reminder of division. Read this [article](http://www.codeavenger.com/2017/05/19/JavaScript-Modulo-operation-and-the-Caesar-Cipher.html) for more explanations.

However, you can easily define the modulo as a custom function and then proceed to the implementation of the Caesar Cipher - which is a very simple form of encryption, in which each letter in the original message is shifted to the left or right by a certain number of positions.

To decrypt the message we simply shift back the letters the same number of positions.

Example:

- JAVASCRIPT becomes MDYDVFULSW if we shift all letters by 3 positions
- MDYDVFULSW turns back to JAVASCRIPT if we shift back all letters by 3 positions.

If after shifting a letter goes outside the range of letters, then the letter is wrapped around in alphabet. Example: Letter Z becomes C if is shifted by 3 positions.

This “wrap-around” effect means use of modulo. In mathematical terms, the above can be expressed as this:

En(x) = (x + n) mod 26

Dn(x) = (x – n) mod 26

Trying to implement this algorithm in JavaScript without the use of a proper modulo operator will produce either incorrect results or a very cryptic and difficult to understand code.

By using a custom modulo function, the code expresses the mathematical equation identically:

```
// Function will implement Caesar Cipher to
// encrypt / decrypt the msg by shifting the letters
// of the message acording to the key
function encrypt(msg, key)
{
    var encMsg = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++)
    {
        var code = msg.charCodeAt(i);

        // Encrypt only letters in 'A' ... 'Z' interval
        if (code >= 65 && code <= 65 + 26 - 1)
        {
            code -= 65;
            code = mod(code + key, 26);
            code += 65;
        }

        encMsg += String.fromCharCode(code);
    }

    return encMsg;
}

// Implement modulo by replacing the negative operand 
// with an equivalent positive operand that has the same wrap-around effect
function mod(n, p)
{
    if ( n < 0 )
        n = p - Math.abs(n) % p;

    return n % p;
}
```

Have fun!

Encrypt a few messages to try out the code. Remember: If you encrypt with a positive key, use the complementary negative key to decrypt it. You can also use this code to decode those ROT13 messages that appears everywhere on the web and newsgroups.

If you want to find out other ways of implementing modulo in JavaScript, please consult the article mentioned at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 2):

(1) You are not iterating through your array `o_letters` properly.

(2) You are going out-of-bounds for your array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < o_letters.length; i++) {
    _x = alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(o_letters[i]) + currentkey + 26) % 26]
    c_text = c_text + _x;
}
```

Also, in your code, you don't need `.split("")` at all.

I would just do this:

```
var currentkey = 5  //for example
function convertKey(str) {
    var ret = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        ret += String.fromCharCode((str.charCodeAt(i) + currentKey + 26) % 26);
    }
    return ret;          
}
```

Or more succinctly (but less efficiently):

```
function convertKey(str) {
    return str.split('').map(function(c) {
       return String.fromCharCode((c.charCodeAt(0) + currentKey + 26) % 26);
    }).join('');       
}
```

Comment: Your solution might work (didn't test it myself), but I can't see where the asker does either of the things you mentioned. His sample code access alphabet[4] every time, and never iterates through the array. Did you mean to say he iterates through the string improperly?

Comment: He iterates through the array `o_letters` improperly. I will add the name of the array to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

// working at https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/caesars-cipher

```
function rot13(str){    

var res = [];

var currentPosition;

var shiftedPosition;

for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    currentPosition = str.charCodeAt(i);

    if (currentPosition<65 || currentPosition>90){
    res.push(String.fromCharCode(currentPosition));
    }

    shiftedPosition = str.charCodeAt(i) - 13;

    if (currentPosition>=65 && shiftedPosition <65){
    res.push(String.fromCharCode(91-(13-(currentPosition-65))));
    }

    if (currentPosition>=78 && currentPosition<=90){
    res.push(String.fromCharCode(shiftedPosition));
    }
  }
return res.join('');`enter code here`
}

// Change the inputs below to test

rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more simple answer:

```js
var rot = {
  'A': 'N',
  'B': 'O',
  'C': 'P',
  'D': 'Q',
  'E': 'R',
  'F': 'S',
  'G': 'T',
  'H': 'U',
  'I': 'V',
  'J': 'W',
  'K': 'X',
  "L": 'Y',
  'M': 'Z',
  'N': 'A',
  'O': 'B',
  'P': 'C',
  'Q': 'D',
  'R': 'E',
  'S': 'F',
  'T': 'G',
  'U': 'H',
  'V': 'I',
  'W': 'J',
  'X': 'K',
  'Y': 'L',
  'Z': 'M',
  ' ': ' ',
  '.': '.',
  '!': '!',
  '?': '?'
};

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR CVMMN!");
// FREE CODE CAMP

function rot13(str) {
  var index = [];
  for (var key in str) {
    for (var property in rot) {
      if (str[key] === property) {
        index.push(rot[property]);
      }
    }
  }
  return index.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rot13(str) {
const alphabet1 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY';
const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
return str
  .split('')
  .map(function(char) {  
    const pos = alphabet.indexOf(char);
    return pos >=0? alphabet1[pos+13] : char;     
  })
  .join('');
}
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to an older question with an accepted answer it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. What advantages does this code offer over the code in the five other answers? Is it something more than ES6 syntax?